# How to pass data from fragment to its viewholder

Tags: android, string, android-intent, fragment

I'm trying to pass data from fragment to its viewHolder. My data is a String value. I will use this data in another activity when I clicked an item. I googled many times but can not find any solution. But I don't know how to do it. Here is my fragment and viewHolder
If you want to know something else let me know.

```
 public class CreateStickerFragment extends Fragment {

    FragmentCreateStickerBinding binding;
    CreateStickerFragmentArgs args;
    CreateStickerAdapter adapter;
    List<Pack> mList;
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
    public CreateStickerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentCreateStickerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        adapter = new CreateStickerAdapter(getActivity());
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), adapter.getGridSize());
        layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(adapter.getSpanSizeLookup());
        binding.recyclerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.recyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        args = CreateStickerFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments());
        String fName = args.getFolderName(); // I want to send this data to my view holder

        if (!AdmUtils.isContextInvalid(getActivity())) {
            mList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 29; i++) {
                mList.add(new Pack());
            }
            adapter.setData(mList);
        }

        return binding.getRoot();
    }
}





//viewholder
    public class CreateStickerViewHolder extends BindableViewHolder<Pack> {

        private TextView numberOfRow;
        private ImageView sticker;

        public CreateStickerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            numberOfRow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberOfRow);
            sticker = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sticker);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindTo(final Activity activity, final Pack model, final int position) {
            numberOfRow.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

            sticker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, StickersCreatorActivity.class);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my adapter ;

```
public class CreateStickerAdapter extends BaseAdapter<Pack, CreateStickerViewHolder> {


    public CreateStickerAdapter(Activity activity) {
        super(activity, R.layout.row_create_sticker);

    }

    @Override
    protected CreateStickerViewHolder createViewHolder(View view) {
        return new CreateStickerViewHolder(view);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make CreateStickerAdapter? If so, you can add a folder name property to it to pass on to your ViewHolder instances.